# Magento : How to Setup Advanced Search in Multicurrency Shop

Tags: magento-1.9, product, multistore, search, currency

I have Magento 1.9 shop with 2 languages (English and Russian) and 2 currency - Euro and RUB (Russian rubles). Currency rate setup correct and in product page I see correct price for both currency.

But in advanced search I need select products by Price, dependency by currency.

Now this search work normal only for one of currency - RUB. 
Then I switch to English site, search result for Price show me products with my wishes price, but in RUB, not in Euro...

**For example** - products have a cost 6300 RUB, in my currency rate it's equal 100 Euro.

In Russian version of site everything works fine but in English I setup Price to 100 Euro. In results, I see all products with price unlit 100 RUB, instead of 100 Euro.

Answer (score 0):

Now I again back to this problem and I think it's bug of core of Magento (
I made some tests on demo sites and found some bug in all sites.
For example I make search for price from 8 to 10 (USD and EURO - dependence in language store)
http://tigermin.demo.emvee-solutions.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?___store=nl&name=&descriptio...
and
http://tigermin.demo.emvee-solutions.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?___store=default&name=&descr...
Search result correct only for USD store (EN), in Dutch store (with EURO) we can see wrong products.